# Conditional Logic Search & Filter Plugin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, searchfiltercollection

I am using [Search & filter Pro](https://searchandfilter.com/) in my WordPress. Now I want to apply conditional Logic between search fields. In the first field, I want to select a product category and in the second input field, I want to display all the model's belongings to that product category. I am using to ACF Pro for all input fields.

Comment: Are you using ACF with custom form? Because otherwise the ACF fields do not respond.

Comment: I am using ACF Form for the front-end.

Comment: I think you need to demonstrate what have you tried. Like, codes for the fields in your front-end form and step by step approach to your expected solution. Otherwise, people would need to spend too much time to help you fix the troubles you may face.